# Convert shapefile to KML without losing symbols

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml, symbology, svg

I am using QGIS 2.2 and want to convert a shapefile containing point coordinates with userdefined svg-symbols to a KML file.

Everything seems to work. The original file is in WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N and I convert it to KML EPSG:4326. When I open the new KML file in Google Earth the position of the points is correct but as a symbol I get Google Earth-Pins.

Is it possible to include the svg-symbol and the label as well in the KML file?

Answer (score 1):

Shapefiles normally don't have styling in themselves. The styles you are talking about in QGIS are stored in the QGIS project files.
Unfortunately there are no functional plugins to convert shapefile to kml along with the QGIS styles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know of any file type, where styling is stored directly?

Comment: Spatialite can store the styles with data. Actually, it seems to be able to store multiple styles which can be switched over.

Comment: If you are only interested in preserving styles for shapefiles and if you are using QGIS only, then you can save the QGIS style as qml file with the same name as the shape file and QGIS will automatically pick it. You can also zip all the files and qgis will directly read the archive.
i.e. if you have roads stored as roads.shp, you can save the QGIS style as roads.qml. QGIS will use the qml file when the shp file is opened. You can zip the roads.shp, roads.prj, roads.dbf ... files along with roads.qml file and use in QGIS without unzipping.